# Extending a Google Sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have my first Google script (below) that checks one cell A8 (DaysToMOT) to see whether a vehicle is less than 16 days to require an MOT, and if so, it sends an email to alert.

Everything works great but it only selects one cell, and so the email it sends out doesn't have the vehicle details (ie: D8 (make), E8 (model), F8(colour), and G8 (VRN).

A Blue Renault Clio car (SHX 6449) will come due for MOT in 15 days - instead of simply - A courtesy car will come due for MOT

I then also need to extend this script so that it goes on to check Row 9, 10, 11, 12 etc etc and perform the same check but only send one email which should include:

A Blue Renault Clio car (SHX 6449) will come due for MOT in 15 days. A Red Kia Sportage car (RHZ 4461) will come due for MOT in 15 days. etc

```
    function CheckMOT() {
// Fetch the No of Days to MOT
  var DaysToMOTRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Courtesy car MOT Tracker").getRange("A8"); 
  var DaysToMOT = DaysToMOTRange.getValue();
  // Check totals sales
  if (DaysToMOT < 16){


  // Fetch the email address
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Courtesy car MOT Tracker").getRange("B1");
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
// Send Alert Email.
var message = 'Hello!\n\nThis is an automated email alert triggered and sent from the Courtesy Tracker Google sheet. \n \nA courtesy car will come due for MOT in '+ DaysToMOT +' days. \n\nPlease book this vehicle in ASAP and update the sheet accordingly. \n\nThanks in advance\n\nBye!' // Second column
var subject = 'URGENT MOT Booking required for Courtesy Car';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
                     }
}
```

[spreadsheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLcVM.png)

Comment: I wonder if you are trying to do too much in one question, which is why the title is very vague. In future, please ask question only, and write a specific title that accurately describes the nature of the problem. "Help required with X" is not specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

### Example:

**Test Data:**

[image]

**Code.gs:**

```
function CheckMOT() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Courtesy car MOT Tracker");
  //get data from row 8 column A - F up until the last row
  var range = sheet.getRange(8, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-7, 6);
  var data = range.getValues();
  //remove sub array that has MOT < 16
  var filteredData = data.filter(data => data[0] < 16);
  var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('EmailTemplate');
  templ.data = filteredData;
  var message = templ.evaluate().getContent();
  var subject = 'URGENT MOT Booking required for Courtesy Car';
  var emailAddress = "insert email address here";
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailAddress,
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: message
  });
}
```

**EmailTemplate.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This is an automated email alert triggered and sent from the Courtesy Tracker Google sheet.</p>
    <br>
    <ul>
    <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
        <li>
          A <?= data[i][4] + " " + data[i][2] + " " + data[i][3] + " car (" + data[i][5] + ")" ?> will come due for MOT in <?= data[i][0]?> days.
        </li>
    <? } ?>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <p>Please book this vehicle in ASAP and update the sheet accordingly.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]

References:

- [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)
- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)
- [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [How to create HTML file in Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html#create_html_files)